# If $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$, and $\{f_n\}$ and f belong to $L^p(E)$, why is $|\|f_n\|_p-\|f\|_p|\le \|f_n-f\|_p$?

Tags: measure-theory

If $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$, and $\{f_n\}$  and $f$ belongs to $L^p(E)$, why is $$|\|f_n\|_p-\|f\|_p|\le \|f_n-f\|_p \text{ ?}$$

Comment: $|\|x\| - \|y\||\le \|x-y\|$ is true for any normed linear space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $$||f_n||= ||f_n -f +f||\le ||f_n-f|| + ||f||$$ and $$||f|| = ||f_n -f_n +f||\le ||f_n-f|| + ||f_n||$$